# Installing Brother DCP-195C on cups

Tags: arm, cups, printer

I try to install my printer (Brother DCP-195C) on my Raspberry Pi. Due to the ARM architecture, I can't use the binary provided by Brother. Therefore I use the source files.

I have installed manually the printer via the local webpage of Cups using the PPD file. After this, I have added the Cups wrapper in `/usr/lib/cups/filter/` (`brlpdwrapperdcp195c`).

When I read the content of `brlpdwrapperdcp195c`, I see that it need a LPD filter (`filterdcp195c`) for working well. This filter is not directly provided by Brother in the source files. So I extracted the `.deb` archive of the `i386` version of the `lpr` driver. The filter is a shell script (`filterdcp195c`). I have copied it on `/opt/brother/Printers/dcp195c/lpd/`.

The LPD filter need some files obtained in the .deb archive (only text files).

The Cups filter need also a compile version of the configuration generator `brcupsconfpt1` provided by Brother in the source archive.

Now I have two issues:

1. `brcupsconfpt1` calls a compiled executable provided in the debian archives (for 32bit and 64bit) but not on the source archive: `brprintconf_dcp195c`.
2. the `lpd` filter calls a compiled executable only provided in the debian archives: `brdcp195cfilter`.

My questions here are:

1. Do I really need all these files?
2. Can I execute 32bit or 64bit compile executable on a ARM architecture? I have red some webpage about the use of `qemu` for executing i386 binaries but I don't know if it is really a good idea....

Comment: The source code for the DCP 195P is available. See http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all&os=128. I downloaded the driver code and verified it contains the C source. it looks like a mess, but might be buildable. It uses autotools, believe it or not.

Comment: As I said the source code contains only the files for building the `brcupsconfpt1` executable but not the other like `brprintconf_dcp195c` and `brdcp195cfilter`. I don't really understand why... Maybe these two files are dependent on the model of the printer but I don't find any information about this...

Comment: Ok, I didn't look at it carefully. You could try asking Brother. Not saying ti would be easy, but you might be able to get through to someone. An alternative approach is to see if there is any contact info in the source files and try that.

Comment: There is not contact information but I will try via the official website....

Comment: See also http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3837

Comment: One other alternative would be to install and share the printer on another system and have the CUPS on the raspberry pi print to it via IPP.

Comment: Yes I think about this but in this case I will not need of the Pi because I can share the printer from the other system and access directly on it. I don't explain the purpose of this but my goal is to build a wireless printer server based on the Pi.